# Non-monotone hazard functions

Tags: distributions, survival, hazard, demography

I should start with the caveat that I am relatively new to Survival analysis. I was watching a Hulu documentary about Crocodiles last night, and they mentioned that baby crocodiles have a low chance of survival when they are young, but "with each passing day they have fewer predators". It seems that this should be true for most (if not all animals) including Humans (maybe to a lesser extent).

It seems that this early stage of life could be modeled with a monotonically decreasing hazard function such as this one from a $Gamma(1/2, 1)$ distribution. [image]

Of course if we want to know the hazard function for the duration of the Crocodiles life, the Hazard function should eventually increase due to old age. All of the common parametric models that I have looked at (weibull, pareto, gamma, etc) are monotone, with the exception of Lognormal which is concave down.

*Are there any simple parametric distributions which have a concave up (bowl shaped) Hazard function?*

Comment: That could be called a *U-formed hazard function*.  See https://books.google.no/books?id=R4drvK7TqysC&pg=PA444&lpg=PA444&dq=U-formed+hazard+function?&source=bl&ots=GwQxSrge15&sig=ACfU3U0ItM2YtcgZdvXxOjvJEIOoByRnpg&hl=no&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwh52U64ngAhXH_SwKHT8HD0gQ6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=U-formed%20hazard%20function%3F&f=false

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yep that looks right. Do you know of any parametric distributions with this type of Hazard function?

Comment: Its also known as a *bathtube function*! See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve) and references there. Specifically [Gompertz-Makeham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz%E2%80%93Makeham_law_of_mortality).  Many more hits on google, one is https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224583969_How_to_Identify_a_Bathtub_Hazard_Rate

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen That's what I'm looking for! If you want to quickly add this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Many questions on site about such hazard functions ... e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bathtub+hazard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you search for is called a [U-formed hazard function](https://books.google.no/books?id=R4drvK7TqysC&pg=PA444&lpg=PA444&dq=U-formed+hazard+function?&source=bl&ots=GwQxSrge15&sig=ACfU3U0ItM2YtcgZdvXxOjvJEIOoByRnpg&hl=no&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwh52U64ngAhXH_SwKHT8HD0gQ6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=U-formed%20hazard%20function%3F&f=false) or [bathtub function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve) (and references in those links). One specific case is the [Gompertz-Makeham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz%E2%80%93Makeham_law_of_mortality) law from demography. An example is the hazard function of humans, high but falling hazard first few years of life, a minimum around 9-10 years of life, then slowly increasing.

Googling with those terms will lead to much information.  Much of interest [here](https://scholar.google.no/scholar?hl=no&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=bathtub+curve+reliability&oq=bathtub+curve)

```
EDIT
```

Some more information. [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257392225_Exponentiated_modified_Weibull_extension_distribution) is a good starting point. They discuss a new extension of the Weibull, which they call EMWE (Exponentiated Modified Weibull Extension distribution) with four parameters, which permits bathtube shaped hazard with form close to hazard functions seen in practice. A plot from that paper is

[image]

with pdf's on the left and corresponding hazard rates on the right.

For reference I will give the cdf and pdf functions:
$$
f(x;\alpha,\beta,\lambda,\gamma)=\lambda\beta\gamma(x/\alpha)^{\beta-1}\exp\left\{(x/\alpha)^\beta+\lambda\alpha(1-e^{(x/\alpha)^\beta} \right\}\cdot \left\{1-e^{\lambda\alpha(1-e^{(x/\alpha)^\beta}}\right\}^{\gamma-1}\\
F(x;\alpha,\beta,\lambda,\gamma)=\left\{1-\exp[\lambda\alpha(1-e^{(x/\alpha)^\beta}]\right\}^\gamma
$$
and the hazard rate is
$$
h(x;\alpha,\beta,\lambda,\gamma)=\frac{\lambda\beta\gamma(x/\alpha)^{\beta-1}\exp[(x/\alpha)^\beta+\lambda\alpha(1-e^{(x/\alpha)^\beta})]}{[1-\exp[\lambda\alpha(1-e^{(x/\alpha)^\beta})]]^{1-\gamma}+\exp\left\{ \lambda\alpha(1-e^{(x/\alpha)^\beta})\right\} -1}
$$
Estimation can be done with maximum likelihood.

Comment: Gompertz-Makeham hazard ($h(x)=\alpha e^{\beta x}+\lambda$) is monotonic-increasing, not U-shaped (the plot in that article is not a plot of a Gompertz-Makeham hazard function; it's actual human mortality rates -- which do decrease and then increase, but Gompertz-Makeham only works  as an approximation from somewhere in the 30s to about 80 or so, give or take)